# Surefire report plugin generates empty report

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have one test, which I run from command line

```
mvn clean site
```

I see that the test completed successfully.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running smoketest.DummyTest
Configuring TestNG with: TestNG652Configurator
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.311 sec - in smoketest.DummyTest

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

However the surefire-report.html shows all zeros. 0 tests, 0 skipped etc. I've probably broken something accidentially, as it used to work last week. Here're my build and reporting sections from pom.xml:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                            <value>false</value> 
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <includes>
                        <include>smoketest/DummyTest.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <reportsDirectory>target/site/</reportsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <dependencyLocationEnabled>false</dependencyLocationEnabled>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

Comment: First remove the configurations from maven-surefire-plugin (includes and report directory) keep the defaults. Furthermore use the same version for maven-surefire-report-plugin. Apart from that choose an more up-to-date version for `maven-project-info-reports-plugin` cause current version is 2.8

Comment: maven-project-info-reports-plugin version 2.0 was chosen because I got issues with 2.8 and found that downgrading helped. If i get rid of includes, then it won't run the tests.

Comment: OK, so the problem was with the custom reports folder. It's working now, after removed the custom reports directory. I wonder why it does not like it?

Comment: Please report the issues.

Comment: The default configuration are choose to get working the different plugins to work correctly together. If you change the default the report plugin can't find the informations.

Comment: and btw, the issue with info reports plugin is that it hangs on generating dependencies report giving warning [WARNING] The repository url 'http://download.oracle.com/maven' is invalid - Repository 'oracleReleases' will be blacklisted.

Comment: This is no issue it's just a warning. Furthermore it sounds you don't use a repository manager.

Comment: Well, it's not just a warning. Before the warning it hangs for about a minute. No, I am not using a repository manager.